# Key-image generation: What does p signify in I = xHp(P)?

Tags: cryptography, key-image

According to the CN whitepaper key image **I** is generated thusly:

I = xH<sub>p</sub>(P)

I understand **P** is the one-time public key for the transaction, **x** the corresponding private key and **H** a deterministic hash function, but what is **<sub>p</sub>**?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two hash functions you'll see referenced often with Monero - there is H<sub>s</sub> and H<sub>p</sub>.

H<sub>s</sub> means "hash to scalar", meaning take a keccak(256) hash and then ensure the result is a "scalar" (a positive integer less than 2<sup>252</sup> + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493).

H<sub>p</sub> means "hash to point", meaning take a keccak(256) hash, interpret the resulting bytes as an elliptic curve point, and then multiply that curve point by 8 to force the resulting point to be in the base point group - i.e. to force it to be the case that there must exist an value x (even though x will be unknown) such that H<sub>p</sub>(..data..) == xG.

Comment: About interpretting the resulting bytes as an ec point - the bytes are interpreted as integer which is the X coordinate of a compressed EC point. You then solve the curve equation for Y which gives you +-Y. How do you pick the correct one?

Comment: @RobinNemeth You can see the source code for Hp() here: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/8f6f674753bae7494e1ee4569004947d47a4e983/src/crypto/crypto.cpp#L481 and there is a full explanation of the ge_fromfe_frombytes_vartime method here: https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/blob/master/whitepaper/ge_fromfe_writeup/ge_fromfe.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Hp is the hash function but SE doesn't support subscripts well. Sometimes it can be written as H_p to avoid confusion.

Comment: FYI, you can use `H<sub>p</sub>` (although not in a code section).